# JPQL query updating CollectionTable

Tags: dictionary, jpa, entity, jpql

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Directory")
@Table(name = "Directory")
public Directory {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
protected String id;

@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "file")
@CollectionTable(name = "Directory_Files", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@Column(name = "hash")
protected Map<File, String> fileToHash;

...

}
```

The hash of a file of a directory should be updated using a JPQL query.

I have tried the following query but it's not working:

```
UPDATE Directory t SET t.Directory_Files.hash = :hash WHERE t.Directory_Files.id = :id AND t.Directory_Files.file = :file
```

Does anyone found the mistake in this query?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Directory_Files" is a database table and doesn't exist in your object model, and so cannot be used in JPQ - You would need to access the fileToHash Map within Directory

Unfortunately JPQL bulk update statements define update Item to be:
update_item ::= [identification_variable.]{single_valued_embeddable_object_field.}*
{state_field | single_valued_object_field} = new_value

fileToHash is a collection and so cannot be used in an Update statement.

You will need to use an SQL query and pass it to EntityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString)

Comment: Is there no other way to access the Map via JPQL? All other queries in my code are based on JPQL and I want to remain consistent.